# HTML/CSS/JS: Fix thead when scroll-y

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

How can I fix the complete **thead** when scrolling in Y-Direction?

It's important to note that the table width is greater than the wrapping div. So scrolling in X-Direction should also scroll the thead - *so separating thead from table is not an option I guess*.

Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxtokb4g/11/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        One
      </th>
      <th>
        Two
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        DataOne
      </td>
      <td>
        DatTwo
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        DataOne
      </td>
      <td>
        DatTwo
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        DataOne
      </td>
      <td>
        DatTwo
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        DataOne
      </td>
      <td>
        DatTwo
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width:80px;
  height:100px;
}
table {
  height:100px;
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Updated the fiddle

Comment: It is expected that you attempt to solve the problem yourself and if you get stuck with a specific coding problem, you ask for help with it.  This is not a free coding service and your question is too broad and therefore off topic for the site

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result is: Scrolling vertical, while thead stays fixed at the top, so you can see always the heads.

Comment: [A small search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcss%5dfixed%20table%20headers) gives interesting results ... What did you find when you did a search?

Comment: @Teemu I did my research. The problem is, if you would have read my question, that every solution does not work with a table like mine --> the table width is greater than the wrapping div, so horizontal-scroll should also scroll the thead, while vertical scroll should fix the thead in current positon and stay on top...

Comment: I read your question, and didn't find much effort ... I'd say x-scroll is irrelevant to the actual task. Separated headers can be aligned with the actual table and scrolled horizontally together without any problems. Veera's interesting suggestion about `sticky` is somewhat new, and not supported in all browsers yet ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me:

```
document.getElementById("TableHead").addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
   this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pxtokb4g/97/

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to assign a function to the scroll event handler using javascript. Use a second table, and if table1 isn't scrolled downwards, have table 2 hidden. When table1 is scrolled downwards call .show() on table2's .

Note: you will need to include JQuery in your HTML.

**HTML**

```
<table id="table-1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
body { height: 1000px; }

#header-fixed { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px; display:none;
    background-color:white;
}
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
```

var $header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

```
if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
    $fixedHeader.show();
}
else if (offset < tableOffset) {
    $fixedHeader.hide();
}
```

});

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/py8b0s7v/

Comment: You need to set #header-fixed to have a fixed position. See CSS in the fiddle at end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
th{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Hi,
Add above Css.

Set position as sticky instead of fixed.

Fixed will "fix" the component to the top of the screen no matter where it is on the page. Sticky uses JS to calculate where it is on the page and only fix to the top when the viewport reaches it. Simply put, use sticky if you want content above the component.